# ESP8266 problem with recieved data trasmission via TCP

Tags: esp8266, softwareserial, python, tcpip

I am having small project where I want to read couple of analog inputs from Arduino UNO, send it via software serial to ESP8266-01 and from that to python server using TCP.

Data is sent to ESP using this code on Arduino UNO

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

    SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
    int pin = 5;

    void setup() {
      mySerial.begin(9600);
      delay(20000);
    }
    void loop() {
      delay(1000);
      int data = analogRead(pin);
      mySerial.println(data);
    }
```

Code on ESP is bellow

```
void loop() {
    while(Serial.available()>0){
    char data = Serial.read();
    client.print(data);
    }
}
```

When data is sent to Python server, it prints it out but data is sent in two seperate parts, so it always looks like this

```
9
59
```

, but number sent from arduino is just 959!

Python server code snipet:

```
while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        print data

        #send data to database
        post.create(
            current = str(data)
        )

         if not data:
            break
```

So the question is, why data sent to server is separated in two parts? Maybe it have to do something with how data is reading from serial on esp?

Comment: Suspect the problem to be with the python code. We'd need a complete minimal verifiable example of it.

Comment: Python server code can be found in [link](https://github.com/austrisu/cs50/blob/master/tcpserver)

Comment: read() in a loop to a buffer, then print() all in once go; the extra read delay might be hampering you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assume all 5 bytes of `959\r\n` are received by the server at the same time. The data is sent byte after byte, based on the `client.print(data)` in the ESP code and assuming the underlying library doesn't buffer bytes before transmitting, so there's no way they'll arrive at the server simultaneously. Most likely, your first pass with `conn.recv(1024)` grabs the first byte `9` and times out. And then on the second pass, the others (at least 2) arrive and are read. The newline between the packets is typical Python 2 `print` behaviour.

What you need to do is parse the data at the server. Basically read data till you get CRLF i.e. `\r\n`, which is a good enough delimiter and you're sending it already anyways, and then use that to know when to write to your database.